# What is the expected running-time of String.replaceFirst("^...") in Java

Tags: java, performance, bytecode

Suppose I have a **very** long string `str = "abcdef..."`.

I want to replace a possible-prefix of `"xyz"` in it, using `str.replaceFirst("^xyz","")`.

What is the expected running-time of the above expression?

Will `replaceFirst` return immediately after the first character, or iterate throughout the entire string?

P.S.: I need an answer from someone who knows how the Java byte-code interpreter works behind the scene when compiling (or shall I say 'interpreting') the `replaceFirst` method of the `String` class.

### UPDATE:

Please consider my question regardless of the intermediate string created in order to return the result. This will happen in any case (no matter what `String` method I use in order to accomplish the desired conversion). I therefore removed the part which refers to the complexity, as it is `O(n)` in any case...

**So to summarize the question:**

Can I assume that the running-time of the **regex-match itself** does not depend on the length of `str`?

Comment: How could it be O(1)? Black magic? What does the byte-code interpreter have to do with the question? Looping is looping, and whatever the byte-code works won't change the complexity of an algorithm.

Comment: Why would you not just use `startsWith` and then `substring`?

Comment: @JB Nizet, could be O(1) because of the `'^'` at the beginning of the regular expression, which indicates that the following data must appear **at the beginning** of the string!!!

Comment: Oh, OK. I missed that, sorry. I wouldn't use a regex to do that. Just use startsWith, as Jon suggests.

Comment: It is O(n+m) for a string of length n and a replacement of length m under the (optimistic) assumption that finding a match for a regex of length k is O(k).

Comment: Thanks Jon Skeet. It's not my question though (I started off with `startsWith` and `substring`, and now I'm asking about `replaceFirst`).

Comment: @Ingo, thanks. I am not asking about a regex in general, I am asking about a regex that starts with `'^'` (which is the "main theme" of the entire question).

Comment: @barakmanos Yes, sure. This is my assumption, plus that the regex is merely a constant string. Let the regex be of length k. Then you need k steps to identify the prefix to remove. Then you essentially append the replacement string (length m) and the rest of the string (n-k). So we have in the worst case, when the regex matches O(m+n-k+k) = O(n+m). This is, btw, the same with startsWith and substring.

Comment: @Ingo: I state in the question a very long string that **doesn't match** the (very short) regex, due to the initial `'^'`. My question here, will `'replaceFirst'` iterate through the entire string, or return immediately upon the first character? The question refers to the specific case enclosed. Thanks

Comment: It should return immediately when it notices that 'x' != 'a' (just like startsWith), then. The O-notation in your question led me to believe we are talking about the general case.

Comment: @ingo, please see my revised question. I **am** talking about the general case (also when there **is** a match), and would like to know whether or not I can assume that the running-time of the **regex-match itself** does not depend on the length of `str`. Thanks

Comment: @barakmanos You can assume that, given a regex `r`, and a string of the form "*MX*", where *M* is the longest possible match for `r`, the length of *X* is immaterial.

Comment: There’s something most people tend to overlook: these replace functions, unlike `a+b.substring(…)`, support back-references to captured groups inside the match. So the replace function has to parse the replacement string as well to see whether it contains back-references. For a `replaceAll` it doesn’t matter, for a `replaceFirst` the surprising answer is that it even depends on the length of the replacement string more than expected.

Comment: @Holger, thanks. I am more concerned with the input string (`str` in my question), which is significantly longer than the regex string.

Comment: Just a side note: It depends heavily on the RegEx itself. See e.g. http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html . In the case that you mentioned, this should be no problem, but one should be aware of this.

Comment: I'm referring to a regex that starts with `'^'`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`replaceFirst` creates a new string by using a StringBuffer on my version of the jdk. So, assuming the length of the regex and the replacement strings are small, it is O(n) due to the string copy, with `n` the length of the initial:

```
public String replaceFirst(String replacement) {
    if (replacement == null)
        throw new NullPointerException("replacement");
    reset();
    if (!find())
        return text.toString();
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    appendReplacement(sb, replacement);
    appendTail(sb);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Notes:

- The regex matching in itself should be O(1) though.
- if there is no match, then `replaceFirst` goes to `return text.toString()` which returns the string itself: **if there is no match, it is an O(1) operation**.
- `startsWith` + `substring` used to be O(1) (when `substring` was a view on the string, i.e. until Java 7u5) but is now O(n) too (since Java 7y6 `substring` creates a new string by copying the underlying char array).

---

**Update**

I have quickly tested the performance of the operation to confirm the above by matching an empty string and a long string with a regex using a `^` anchor and one without it. The result (in nanosecond per call):

```
p1s1 (empty string, "^x")   47.561 nsec/op
p1s2 (long string, "^x")    50.753 nsec/op
p2s1 (empty string, "x")    47.526 nsec/op
p2s2 (long string, "x")    131.015 nsec/op
```

So you can see that the `"^x"` regex drops the analyses at the first character because the time is (almost) the same with an empty or long string.

Code, using jmh for benhcmarking:

```
private String s1 = "";
private String s2 = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" +
                    "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" +
                    "x";
private static final Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("^x");
private static final Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("x");

@GenerateMicroBenchmark
public boolean p1s1() { return p1.matcher(s1).find(); }

@GenerateMicroBenchmark
public boolean p1s2() { return p1.matcher(s2).find(); }

@GenerateMicroBenchmark
public boolean p2s1() { return p2.matcher(s1).find(); }

@GenerateMicroBenchmark
public boolean p2s2() { return p2.matcher(s2).find(); }
```

Comment: Uhh no. Consider `"aa".replaceFirst("^a", some)` where `some` is some megabytes of string data .... also, regex match is proportional (not necessarily linear) to the length of the regex.

Comment: @Ingo The matching is indeed `O(m)` with `m` the length of the regex (the engine only needs to read a maximum of `m` characters) but I assumed the length of the regex was fixed, therefore still an O(1) vs the length of the string. Your first point makes sense. I have added my assumptions.

Comment: So if we put aside the new string created, which obviously makes the complexity `O(n)` no matter how I implement it (updated my question accordingly, due to your note here)... then the regex matching will be done in `O(1)` **when there is no match**, and in `O(m)` **when there is a match**?

Comment: Yes it is O(1) when there is no match as shown by the micro benchmark in my updated answer.

Comment: Uh oh, when there is no match, it obviously depends on the location of the first non-matching character. It *might* be the first one like you assume but it also might be the last one. So it’s somewhere between `O(1)` and `O(m)` leaving an average of `O(m/2)` which is still linear, not constant.

Comment: And still not dependent on `n`? (unless `n < m`, which is not the case in my question).

Comment: @barak manos: as long as your pattern has an anchor and no unlimited quantifiers as in your question it does not depend on the `String` size `n`.

Comment: @assylias, thank you very much for the extremely detailed and useful answer!